# I try to add element to structure, and I want to add to this element parent ID

Tags: structure

Form code:

```
<section class="membersTitle" >
    <label>Date</label>
    <select name="fields[parent][]">
    {% set entries = craft.entries.section('order').level(1) %}
        {% for entry in entries %}
            <option value="{{ entry.id }}">{{ entry.title }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</section>
```

I want to choose Parent from list, and I want to add the element to parent.

Answer (score 2):

The `fields` array may only contain names that represents handles in your `fieldLayout` but the `parent` attribute is a property of your object rather than a field - you can set it via `parentId`. You may want to inspect your CP form in order to see how you need to define attributes

```
<section class="membersTitle" >
    <label>Date</label>
    <select name="parentId">
        {% for entry in craft.entries.section('order').level(1).find() %}
            <option value="{{ entry.id }}">{{ entry.title }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</section>
```

Comment: thx Robin, so how I can add entry as a child, is it possible?

Comment: With the code above (?)

Comment: if you know another way, tell me pls

Comment: There is no easier way.. Specify the `parentId` attribute and you are done. You can as well create a custom query to change all necessary columns by hand but just setting the parentId is the way to go